# pysnmp trap receiver - processing with asyncio queue (w/o threads)

Tags: python, python-asyncio, pysnmp

My goal is to have a pure asyncio implementation to receive and process SNMP-TRAPS with pysnmp. So far I only managed to accomplish it by using (one or several) separate Threads.

The examples I have found for pysnmp is using a sync callback Function (cbFun). I did not manage/understand how to make a async function there.

Below example works fine for me but is using a separate Thread (or pool). It would be nice to have something in the lines of:

```
queue = asyncio.Queue()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(run_daemon)
loop.create_task(process_trap)
loop.run_forever()
```

but I did not manage to do it this way because of the cbFun.

here is my working (threaded) example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8

import asyncio
import concurrent.futures

from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncio.dgram import udp
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import ntfrcv

class SnmpTrapDaemon():

    @staticmethod
    def run_daemon(pool):

        # Create SNMP engine with autogenernated engineID and pre-bound
        # to socket transport dispatcher
        snmpEngine = engine.SnmpEngine()

        # Transport Setup
        config.addTransport(
            snmpEngine,
            udp.domainName,
            udp.UdpTransport().openServerMode(('0.0.0.0', '162'))
        )

        # SNMPv1/2c setup
        config.addV1System(
            snmpEngine, 'public', 'public')

        # Callback function for receiving notifications
        # noinspection PyUnusedLocal
        def cbFun(snmpEngine, stateReference, contextEngineId,
                contextName, varBinds, cbCtx):

            trap = {}
            for oid, val in varBinds:
                trap[oid.prettyPrint()] = val.prettyPrint()
            pool.submit(asyncio.run, process_trap(trap))

        # Register SNMP Application at the SNMP engine
        ntfrcv.NotificationReceiver(snmpEngine, cbFun)

        snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)
        try:
            print(f'Trap Listener started on port 162. Press Ctrl-c to quit.')
            snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('user quit')
        finally:
            snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()

async def process_trap(trap):
    print('Processing TRAP - this might take while...')
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    for item in trap.items():
        print(item)
    print('...done')

def main():
    print('Starting SNMP-TRAP Processor. Test with "snmptrap -v2c -c public 127.0.0.1:162 123 1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 s test"')
    pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
    SnmpTrapDaemon.run_daemon(pool)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me without threading:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8

import asyncio

from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncio.dgram import udp
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import ntfrcv

def run_daemon():

    # Create SNMP engine with autogenernated engineID and pre-bound
    # to socket transport dispatcher
    snmpEngine = engine.SnmpEngine()

    # Transport Setup
    config.addTransport(
        snmpEngine,
        udp.domainName,
        udp.UdpTransport().openServerMode(('0.0.0.0', '162'))
    )

    # SNMPv1/2c setup
    config.addV1System(
        snmpEngine, 'public', 'public')

    # Callback function for receiving notifications
    # noinspection PyUnusedLocal
    def cbFun(snmpEngine, stateReference, contextEngineId,
            contextName, varBinds, cbCtx):

        trap = {}

        print('Notification from ContextEngineId "%s", ContextName "%s"' % (contextEngineId.prettyPrint(),
                                                                            contextName.prettyPrint()))

        for oid, val in varBinds:
            trap[oid.prettyPrint()] = val.prettyPrint()
        asyncio.create_task(process_trap(trap))

    

    # Register SNMP Application at the SNMP engine
    ntfrcv.NotificationReceiver(snmpEngine, cbFun)
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)
    try:
        print(f'Trap Listener started on port 162. Press Ctrl-c to quit.')
        snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('user quit')
    finally:
        snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()

async def process_trap(trap):
    print('Processing TRAP - this might take while...')
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    for item in trap.items():
        print(item)
    print('...done')

def main():
    print('Starting SNMP-TRAP Processor. Test with "snmptrap -v2c -c public 127.0.0.1:162 123 1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 s test"')
    run_daemon()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```